# Can I overload a function template with a regular function of different return type?

Tags: c++

I've gone over quite a few similar but not quite the same questions; I've implemented a simple timer class with an "elapsed" method which by "default" is itself templated on desired return type and units.

But in cases where I might need to do duration arithmetic, I'd like the elapsed function to also be capable of returning a duration. So I tried "overloading" the template with a regular function.

```
// timer.hpp
#pragma once

#include <chrono>

template <typename clock_t> class timer {
  // ... //
  public:
  template <typename rep_t, typename unit_t>
  rep_t elapsed() const; // templated version

  typename clock_t::duration elapsed() const; // non-templated version    
};

template <typename clock_t>
template <typename rep_t, typename unit_t>
rep_t timer<clock_t>::elapsed() const {
  // Evaluates a duration and casts it to rep_t
}

template <typename clock_t>
typename clock_t::duration timer<clock_t>::elapsed() const {
  // Returns the duration directly
}
```

This appears to work and there shouldn't be any ambiguity. The correct functions are being called. But since I couldn't quite find examples of this, I'd like to know if this kind of "overloading" is even legal, if there is ambiguity, other issues etc.

Edit: cleaned example code.

Edit 2: removed default template parameters.

Comment: Is this really a *minimal* example to reproduce your question?  It seems like there's a lot of domain-specific fluff not necessary to ask a question about the syntax of using templates.  If possible please clean it up to be the least amount of code to exhibit your question in C++ (i.e. no code about computing time or whatever)

Comment: @xaxxon Since the whole thing is nested in a templated class I was unsure if cutting it down to just the function itself would actually change the problem. But I will omit certain unecessary bits.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I played around with it a bit.. it looks like if it can deduce the parameter type, it will prefer the templated version of the function.  If it can't then it will try to use a non-templated function instead.  Whatever the rules are, I would recommend staying away from this due to the likelihood of something seemingly unrelated subtly changing and drastically changing the chosen function, but it doesn't seem illegal.

Comment: Here's a link to a very minimal repro case you can play around with: https://godbolt.org/z/nq8dsA

Comment: @xaxxon Awesome site. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: If you've never been there before, you probably haven't experienced 25% of how awesome it is.  It has a ton of libraries you can include.  The ASM is color coded to match the source.   You can have it use multiple compilers at the same time and customize the output windows in tons of ways.   It has experimental compilers for future, proposed c++ features, etc.   Matt Godbolt does amazing things for C++

Comment: To make the code clear, the template version should not have default unit specified.

Comment: @Phil1970 Fixed. Though I feel like it makes "clock_t::duration" less clear.